# IPv4 as default IP in dual stack

Tags: ip, ipv6, ipv4

I am having an issue in prioritizing my IP network in Windows 8 to use IPv4 as default. Currently when ever I browser IP detection sites, they show me IPv6 address. How do I change this behavior??

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See: http://superuser.com/questions/436574/ipv4-vs-ipv6-priority-in-windows-7

Answer (score 1):

Modern browsers will use IPv6 when it is available. As you see IPv6 addresses in address detection sites it means it works. Why disable it then? Be glad it works! :-)

Comment: since browsers use IPv6 by default so those site that has IPv6 implemented, its transfer rate will be slower as the speed test result shows, because connection is not native. So I was wishing to get priorities reversed.

Comment: `Why disable it then? Be glad it works!` - Perhaps he is getting his IPv6 over a low latency link.  Perhaps there is some kind of routing issue or filtering issue over his IPv6 network.  There are lots of reasons why you may want to choose one network path over another.

Comment: @AzfarNiaz In that case you will never use IPv6, so why have the tunnel at all?

Comment: @Micheal Hampton, just because of curiosity :)  !!!

Comment: `because of curiosity` very good reason! :-)

Comment: IPv6 should be disable as a last resort. We are in the midst of a transition to IPv6. If you find issues such as higher latency with IPv6, talk to your provider. The ISP may have incongruent IPv4 and IPv6 peering topologies. The engineers may not understand the ramifications to the user experience. We need more users using IPv6 in order to pressure infrastructure and content companies to fix problems. Most users will not be as technical as the OP and won't realize that turning off the IPv6 is an option...for now.

Answer (score 1):

Applications implementing [RFC6555](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6555) (Happy Eyes) do not require such changes, the majority of modern web browsers have already implemented it.

In the case of applications not implementing *Happy Eyes* the easiest route is to disable the IPv6 stack as workarounds may not be available for all supported platforms.

The RFC discusses an interesting point that the faster path is not always the best path as it can place additional undue burden on the IPv4 route when resources should be deployed to upgrade the IPv6 route.